# Python 3 program returns error "EOFError: EOF when reading a line"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the problem: "EOFError: EOF when reading a line" and I don't know why:

```
string=input("Please enter a string: ")
word=string[0]
print(word+string.replace(word,'e')[1:])
```

Comment: I ran your code without any error.

Comment: your code is working fine in python 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EOF Error tends to come up when you the input is empty.
For example, if you open Python shell

```
x = input("Enter something:")
```

And then just Enter, EOF error will show up.
All in all, I think it's an issue in the IDE you're using. Maybe give more details about your environment.